# How to implement Parcelable on an external object?

Tags: android

My app queries a service using an external library in the form of a JAR file. When I query this service, I get back a List of objects (object is used generically, not Object), which do not implement Parcelable in their current form. I need to send one of these objects between activities, so I am assuming that I need to somehow make them implement Parcelable. However, I'm not sure how to do so if they are not my objects, and all the tutorials I've found online seem to only deal with objects that the author created for his own project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use your Application to store these objects. Simple subclass Application, make it a singleton and declare it in your Manifest.xml

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final MyApplication instance;

    public static MyApplication getInstace() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
    }

    private MyObject myObj;

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return this.myObj;
    }

    public void setMyObject(MyObject myObj) {
        this.myObj = myObj;
    }
}
```

Then later on you can store it:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().setMyObject(anObject);
```

And recover it:

```
MyObject anObject = MyApplication.getInstance().getMyObject();
```

Remember that:

1. Declare the MyApplication class as the Application in the Manifest.xml
2. If your process is killed or exited, then your data won't be available anymore.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I wanted to do it by passing the object to the activity (and maybe eventually I'll change it to work that way in the future), but for now this was the simplest and most effective solution.

Comment: I do not understand why you are making MyApp a singleton since the OS seems to create a _single_ instance of MyApp and getApplicationContext() seems to always return the same single instance of MyApp created by the OS. Such that the "global point of access" will return a single instance of the class.

Comment: @JAL yes, it's only for convenience purposes, otherwise you will need to do something like getApplicationContext() and then cast it to your Application class. Note that the instace is assigned in the overrided onCreate method, so it's the same instace the OS creates.

Comment: How do I declare the MyApplication class as the Application in the Manifest.xml?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can instantiate new copies of the object yourself, you can always use composition and implement your own Parcelable data transfer object to do the transfer:

1. Create a new Parcelable class, let's call it PObject.
2. Add a constructor for PObject that takes in a copy of the object that does not implement Parcelable.
3. Create a method on PObject that returns a fully instantiated copy of the object that does not implement Parcelable.

   You should now be able to use the PObject implementation to transfer the objects.

The documentation of the [Parcelable interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) shows a basic example to transfer an integer.

Of course, this assumes you need Parcelable: if the Activities are in the same process you can probably just pass them using a global static. Its not the prettiest, but its often good enough.

Comment: How would I know if they are in the same process or not? It's a relatively simple app; I have one main ListActivity that displays a list of titles, and then when that title is clicked displays more information in another activity. The object I'm trying to pass between the two activities simply contains information regarding the title and description, among other parameters.

Comment: If they are part of the same APK then they are probably in the same process.

Comment: It is better (the code looks way better) to implement Parcelable as you first suggest and use composition over your Object than storing it as a global static.